# Stored procedures in gremlin CosmosDB

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I'm new to `gremlin` and `cosmos DB` and was trying to use `Stored Procedure` in cosmos DB gremlin API.

I started with [Quick-start-nodejs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-nodejs) doc for creating a node.js app, connected with CosmosDB gremlin API. Now I want to use Stored Procedure in that app.
I found only single [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming) for stored procedures in cosmos DB, and that's only for Document DB (in SQL). I didn't found any doc related to stored procedure in gremlin.

Can anyone guide me, how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. And found that Cosmos DB in Gremlin or Graph mode does not support stored procedures. You can create them from UI but because you can not use any Gremlin query or have trigger - they are useless. Also there is no documentation on it.

I have found a post from March 2019 that stored procedures are on the roadmap for Germlin
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/20115355-gremlin-queries-from-stored-procedures

Personally, for my use case I am considering use of Neo4j instead of Cosmos because of the lack of stored procedures

Answer (score -1):

What's your use case?

Gremlin is a language for traversing graph. Gremlin has no knowledge of CosmosDB stored procedure and hence you can't really execute stored procedure via gremlin.

However, CosmosDB is multi-model. You can talk to it via gremlin as well as native DocumentDB API.

You should look into how to execute stored procedure via DocumentDB API.

Comment: Actually I want to add some edges every time a new vertex is created. For example, whenever a vertex with the label `EMPLOYEE` is created, an edge to the vertex `COMPANY` must be automatically created.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comment on the first answer to the question: "Actually I want to add some edges every time a new vertex is created. For example, whenever a vertex with the label EMPLOYEE is created, an edge to the vertex COMPANY must be automatically created." [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571778/stored-procedures-in-gremlin-cosmosdb/47576459?noredirect=1#comment82106346_47573315), you can look into TinkerPop's [EventStrategy](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_eventstrategy).

EDIT:

Adding essential parts from the link above in case the link changes:

The purpose of the EventStrategy is to raise events to one or more MutationListener objects as changes to the underlying Graph occur within a Traversal. Such a strategy is useful for logging changes, triggering certain actions based on change, or any application that needs notification of some mutating operation during a Traversal. If the transaction is rolled back, the event queue is reset.

The following events are raised to the MutationListener:

- New vertex
- New edge
- Vertex property changed
- Edge property changed
- Vertex property removed
- Edge property removed
- Vertex removed
- Edge removed

To start processing events from a Traversal first implement the MutationListener interface. An example of this implementation is the ConsoleMutationListener which writes output to the console for each event. The following console session displays the basic usage:

```
gremlin> import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.event.*
==>org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.empty.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphml.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.*, org.apache.commons.configuration.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.strategy.decoration.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.strategy.optimization.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.strategy.finalization.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.strategy.verification.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.bulkdumping.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.bulkloading.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.clustering.peerpressure.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.traversal.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.ranking.pagerank.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.traversal.strategy.optimization.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.traversal.strategy.decoration.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.iterator.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.IoCore.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.P.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.Computer.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.TimeUtil.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.SackFunctions.Barrier.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty.Cardinality.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Column.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Direction.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Operator.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Order.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Pop.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Scope.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.T.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.TraversalOptionParent.Pick.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.message.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.*, groovyx.gbench.*, groovyx.gprof.*, static groovyx.gprof.ProfileStaticExtension.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.giraph.process.computer.*, org.apache.hadoop.conf.*, org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.*, org.apache.hadoop.fs.*, org.apache.hadoop.util.*, org.apache.hadoop.io.*, org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.*, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.util.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.graphson.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.script.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.process.computer.mapreduce.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.dsl.credential.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.dsl.credential.CredentialGraph.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.*, static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.process.traversal.LabelP.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.structure.io.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.process.computer.*, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.event.*
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> l = new ConsoleMutationListener(graph)
==>MutationListener[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]]
gremlin> strategy = EventStrategy.build().addListener(l).create()
==>EventStrategy
gremlin> g = graph.traversal().withStrategies(strategy)
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property('name','stephen')
Vertex [v[13]] added to graph [tinkergraph[vertices:7 edges:6]]
==>v[13]
gremlin> g.E().drop()
Edge [e[7][1-knows->2]] removed from graph [tinkergraph[vertices:7 edges:6]]
Edge [e[8][1-knows->4]] removed from graph [tinkergraph[vertices:7 edges:5]]
Edge [e[9][1-created->3]] removed from graph [tinkergraph[vertices:7 edges:4]]
Edge [e[10][4-created->5]] removed from graph [tinkergraph[vertices:7 edges:3]]
Edge [e[11][4-created->3]] removed from graph [tinkergraph[vertices:7 edges:2]]
Edge [e[12][6-created->3]] removed from graph [tinkergraph[vertices:7 edges:1]]
By default, the EventStrategy is configured with an EventQueue that raises events as they occur within execution of a Step. As such, the final line of Gremlin execution that drops all edges shows a bit of an inconsistent count, where the removed edge count is accounted for after the event is raised. The strategy can also be configured with a TransactionalEventQueue that captures the changes within a transaction and does not allow them to fire until the transaction is committed.
```

WARNING
EventStrategy is not meant for usage in tracking global mutations across separate processes. In other words, a mutation in one JVM process is not raised as an event in a different JVM process. In addition, events are not raised when mutations occur outside of the Traversal context.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18113668)

Comment: Thanks; I added the relevant text and code examples.

Comment: None of this is going to work on Cosmos, it's not fully Tinkerpop compliant only a subset of actual Gremlin has been covered let alone more advanced stuff provided by the actual graph engine